# Connecting Mongo Atlas with AWS MSK without VPC

Tags: mongodb-atlas, aws-msk, aws-msk-connect

I was trying to connect Mongo Atlas from Amazon AWS MSK Connect , but not able to connect it.
I had provided the mongo connection uri , when creating a MSK connector.

There are solutions in which VPC and Private Endpoints are being used . but is there no way to connect just using ConnectionURI ?

On local Machine , running own Kafka and Kafka Connect Process , Its able to connect there.

So ,

1. what may be restricting AWS MSK to connect to Atlas ?
2. why same issue is not being faced on local setup ?

Thanks.

This is the error I received on capturing logs in MSK COnnect.

```
INFO Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0-shard-00-00.fw7ue.mongodb.net:27017 (org.mongodb.driver.cluster:76)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff] com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:180)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:193)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:157)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff] Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:305)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  ... 4 more
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff] [2023-04-19 17:34:48,945] INFO Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0-shard-00-01.fw7ue.mongodb.net:27017 (org.mongodb.driver.cluster:76)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff] com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:180)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:193)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:157)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff] Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:305)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:107)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65)
[Worker-05d1c929e679cbbff]  ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the network configuration. In order to connect to Mongo Atlas, MSK Connect should talk to the network hence the solution was to create a NAT gateway and route traffic via that.

[Enabling internet access for Amazon MSK Connect](https://web.archive.org/web/20230521235928/https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/msk-connect-internet-access.html)